# INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE appears to not work

Tags: python, mysql, sql

So, I've been trying to create a python web app that shouldn't be hard at all, but I appear to be doing something very wrong.

```
**def insert(self, user, points):
    self.cur.execute('INSERT INTO points (user, points) VALUES ("' + user + '",' + str(points) + ') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE points=points+' + str(points))

    self.db.commit()**
```

that's the source code im using, i'm trying to insert a user + their "points" into a table, everything about this seems to work perfectly fine, but it doesn't update, instead, when I call for insert() it ADDS a new user with 1 point.

```
    User    Points
[name]          1
[same name]     1
```

How do I make the UPDATE work?

Comment: FYI: Instead of repeating `str(points)` in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause, you can use the SQL `VALUES(points)` to refer to the value that would have been inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
INSERT INTO points(user, points)
    VALUES ("' + user + '",' + str(points) + ')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE points=points+' + str(points);
```

In order for this to work, you need a unique key on the table.  Methinks you want `user` to be unique, so do:

```
create unique index idx_points_user on points(user)
```

An index on `points(user, points)` won't do what you want.